# Check if a descendant has activeFocus == true in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent

Inside a deeply nested QML GUI, is there an easy way to find out if any child or grandchild etc of an Item has `activeFocus == true` ?

```
Item {
  id: intermediateItem
  visible: anyDescendantHasActiveFocus(intermediateItem) ? true : false
  Item {
    Item {
      Item {
        id: hasActiveFocus
        Component.onCompleted: hasActiveFocus.forceActiveFocus()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Loop through all the children and check `activeFocus`? Doesn't it easy enough?

Comment: `O(n)`  // for n children? Also that would have to be done recursively following the suggested strategy. I was hoping for a built in way in QML.

Comment: I do not think it would be right to implement such a costly and rarely used function in QML `Item`. So yes, you have to loop recursively through all the children. But I would do that in a declarative way ie, I would inform parent from children about changing the property, for example, in children: `onActiveFocusChanged: {if(activeFocus ) parent.focusCounter--; else parent.focusCounter++; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of drilling down the hierarchy from your base ancestor, you can go up from the current [`activeFocusItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#activeFocusItem-attached-prop):

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    function anyDescendantHasActiveFocus(ancestor) {
        let item = ancestor.Window.activeFocusItem;
        while (item) {
            if (item === ancestor)
                return true;
            item = item.parent;
        }
        return false;
    }

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 10
        Repeater {
            model: 3
            Rectangle {
                width: 200
                height: 100
                border.width: 1
                border.color: anyDescendantHasActiveFocus(this) ? "red" : "black"
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 10
                    border.width: 1
                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 10
                        border.width: 1
                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 10
                            border.width: 1
                            Button {
                                anchors.centerIn: parent
                                text: "Focus me"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```